# Error in checkout while using Bitcoin Payments by BitcoinWay with WooCommerce, "CurveCurveFp Object"

Tags: php

I have bit coin installed on a clients wordpress site. Upon checkout, when I check Bitcoin as my payment, and click Place Order, the order does not go through and I get the following error at the top of the checkout page:

```
CurveCurveFp Object
(
    [a:protected] => 0
    [b:protected] => 7
    [prime:protected] => 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
)
 does not contain point ( 20139727203196486522876591193063649819462947761513549103823800141681658369 , 369049320460203173903206256216019890340108033867982827520 )
```

Here is the URL: https://www.goldextradellc.com/checkout/

Any help / suggestions you can give me would be great. Thanks

Comment: I assume you're using some sort of wordpress  Bitcoin plugin that integrates with WooCommerce. Which one?

Comment: a, b, and prime seem to correspond to Bitcoin's curve constants. So it seems like it's complaining that a key that it was given or that it created is not a valid public key. I dunno how useful that is.

Comment: @NickODell those x,y coordinates certainly don't *look* valid (their hex representations contain a whole bunch of zeros; I don't doubt that it's not located on the curve although I didn't bother actually checking). (agreed that a, b, and prime are correct.)

Comment: I used Bitcoin Payments for WooCommerce by BitcoinWay plugin

Answer (score 1):

FYI: this site seems to be using the [Bitcoin Payments for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bitcoin-payments-for-woocommerce/installation/) plugin. If I'm wrong, then please disregard this answer.

This plugin is not compatible with the current version of Electrum. Give this a try (these instructions are for Windows):

1. Start -> Run (or press the Windows key + r), then type in `%appdata%\Electrum\wallets` and press OK.
2. Take a backup of all of your wallet files in this folder. If you have any funds in your wallet(s) and skip this step, *you may lose those funds*, so be *careful!*
3. Close this folder, and open a new one: Start -> Run (or press the Windows key + r), then type in `%appdata%` and press OK.
4. Delete the `Electrum` folder.
5. Uninstall Electrum.
6. Download and install `electrum-1.9.8-setup.exe` from https://download.electrum.org/.
7. Follow the normal install instructions for the plugin.

After you've tested it and have gotten it working, it is safe (and recommended) to upgrade Electrum to the newest version. You only need the old version when you first create your wallet. After upgrading, you can open your wallet backups you made in step 3 to access any old funds (but you *can't* use these wallets with the plugin).

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. And yes I'm using woocommerce

Comment: @GregRobertson As Nick ODell pointed out above, there exist *more than one* bitcoin plugin for WooCommerce. I took an educated guess as to which one you're using, but if I was wrong, then the answer is probably wrong too....

Comment: Your right Christopher, I used the Bitcoin Payments for WooCommerce plugin Thanks

Comment: Yes, It solved my problem thanks.

I put the 2 files back to their original code, downloaded and installed wallet 1.9.8., got the new key, entered it into WooCommerce and everything is good.

Thanks